# Selecionar elementos ignorando itens específicos SIMPLE HTML DOM

Tags: php, dom

Estou parseando uma tabela. Mas dentro dessa tabela existe uma outra tabela e está difícil encontrar os elementos inteiros. Vou colar o código para exemplificar melhor.

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>
        Dados Gerais
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>
        <div>Dados de Nomes</div>
     </td>
     <td>
        <table>
           <tr>
              <td>
                 Nome
              </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>
                 João da Silva
              </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>
                 Maria da Silva
              </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>
        <div>Dados de Técnicos</div>
     </td>
     <td>
        <table>
           <tr>
              <td>
                 Data
              </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>
                 10/09/2019
              </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>
                 11/09/2019
              </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
     </td>
  </tr>
```

Faço o find dos tr ele retorna todos os tr

```
$trs = $tabela->find('tr');
```

Mas gostaria que ele ignorasse os tr que estão dentro da tabela que está dentro da tabela.

---------- Pergunta editada  ----------

Bom, eu fiz um foreach para contar quantos trs tinham dentro da tabela e fiz o find com a quantidade exata de trs. Exemplo segue abaixo.

```
$contar = $tabela->find('tr');
$c=0;
foreach ($contar as $k) {
    $c++;
}
$trCorreto = $trs[$c];
```

Comment: Não porque eu não quero o primeiro tr, quero o terceiro tr onde tem o td "Dados Técnicos"

Comment: Postei a solução que consegui

Comment: Uai, mas aí vc tá fazendo algo completamente diferente do que perguntou e comentou. Releia a sua pergunta e veja que a solução que vc colocou -- o que é errado, pois o campo de pergunta é apenas para "a pergunta" --, está totalmente alheia a solução que colocou.

Comment: Não está diferente! Apenas usei uma solução paralela. Eu queria que ele ignorasse os TR dentro do segundo TR. O que fiz foi contar os TR dentro do segundo TR para pulá-los quando eu fizer o loop. O que dá no mesmo. Entendo que essa não é a melhor solução ou a solução oficial, mas ela resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, sua pergunta não está muito clara mas pelo que entendi você não quer selecionar os elementos `tr` das tabelas aninhadas.

Então para obter somente os elementos `tr` que são filhos, você pode utilizar a função do JQuery chamada [children](https://api.jquery.com/children/).

```
$('#tabela').children('tr');
```